# How can I open an account with a bank in Ethers?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin

How can I open an account with a bank in Ethereum? Can I trade it? Which banks support cryptocurrencies? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

Cryptocurrencies generally aren't stored in a bank, since the main benefit of cryptocurrency is that you, the user, are in complete control of your funds.

That said, the closest thing to a bank in the cryptocurrency world is an exchange. [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/) is an excellent choice, and if you want to use it in conjunction with USD banking services, [USAA](https://www.usaa.com/inet/wc/account_management_coinbase_landing?adID=VURL_externalaccounts) allows you to view your Coinbase balance alongside your USD accounts.

Please note, however, that unlike a regular bank, Coinbase is not insured by the FDIC, so if they are hacked or run away with your money, the money is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

Currently there are no state recognized banks who offer any cryptocurrency services. Banks are regulated industry. Cryptocurrencies have very little regulation currently and much of the community is against it.

Instead, open an account in cryptocurrency exchange or service like Coinbase.

Answer (score 1):

### No, no banks are supporting cryptocurrencies as of now.

*Some good reads*

1. [Legality of bitcoin by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_bitcoin_by_country)
2. [Banks And Cryptocurrency](http://leadhounds.net/banks-and-cryptocurrency/)
3. [What banks do accept bitcoin?](https://www.quora.com/What-banks-do-accept-bitcoin)

*Stories*

> **Barclays** is not accepting or holding any Bitcoin as some outlets have suggested,” Barclays’ Candice Macdonald, Vice President of Group Media Relations, wrote. “No Bitcoin is travelling through Barclays systems
>
> **Bank of America** Files [Patent](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=%22Wire%20Transfers%20Using%20Cryptocurrency%22&OS=%22Wire%20Transfers%20Using%20Cryptocurrency%22&RS=%22Wire%20Transfers%20Using%20Cryptocurrency%22) for Cryptocurrency Wire Transfer System

These are some stories i collected form internet, and adding here for future sake.